# PHP loops and array help, looping through results and targeting only specific records

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Scenario:

I downloaded a Joomla extension and am editing the php file to alter the layout of the module. Now in the source code of the file lies this bit of code.

```
<?php if ( !empty($this->fields) ) { ?>
    foreach ($this->fields as $field)
    {
        echo RSDirectoryFilter::getInstance($field, $options)->generate();
    }
} ?>
```

which cycles through a list of form fields and prints out the fields and their options.

what i want to do is apply some styling to a specific form field only.

that loop printed out 3 fields altogether. My first step was to add a print_r($field) into the loop to see what data is stored within the $field parameter. each field was an array of data

this is what it printed out

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [field_type_id] => 1 [name] => title [column_name] => title [form_field_name] => title [required] => 1 [published] => 1 [field_type] => title [core] => 1 [create_column] => 0 [expect_value] => 1 [properties] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object ( [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( [form_caption] => Title [default_value] => [field_prepend] => [field_append] => [show_help_tip] => 1 [help_tip] => [show_help_text] => 1 [help_text_position] => block [help_text] => [readonly] => 0 [additional_html_attributes] => [id] => 1 [searchable_simple] => 1 [searchable_advanced] => textbox [searchable_advanced_caption] => Keywords [searchable_advanced_items] => [searchable_advanced_condition_type] => containing [default_validation_rule] => none [extra_accepted_chars] => [regex_syntax] => [custom_validation_rule] => [characters_limit] => 0 [validation_message] => There was an error with the title field. ) [separator] => . ) ) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 31 [field_type_id] => 11 [name] => status [column_name] => f_31 [form_field_name] => status [required] => 1 [published] => 1 [field_type] => dropdown [core] => 0 [create_column] => 1 [expect_value] => 1 [properties] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object ( [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 31 [help_text] => [additional_html_attributes] => [credits] => 0 [default_values] => Stolen Lost Found [default_value] => [size] => 1 [multiple] => 0 [field_prepend] => [field_append] => [show_help_tip] => 1 [help_tip] => [show_help_text] => 1 [help_text_position] => block [listing_caption] => status [dependency] => 0 [items] => Stolen Lost Found [form_caption] => status [searchable_simple] => 1 [searchable_advanced] => dropdown [searchable_advanced_caption] => Listing Status [use_dependency] => 1 [use_field_items] => 1 [searchable_advanced_items] => [searchable_advanced_condition_type] => strict [validation_message] => Invalid input. ) [separator] => . ) ) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 34 [field_type_id] => 17 [name] => date-of-incident [column_name] => f_34 [form_field_name] => date_of_incident [required] => 1 [published] => 1 [field_type] => calendar [core] => 0 [create_column] => 1 [expect_value] => 1 [properties] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object ( [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( [form_caption] => Date Of Incident [listing_caption] => Date Of Incident [default_date] => [min_date] => [max_date] => [date_mask] => d F Y [time_mask] => g:i a [calendar_layout] => flat [readonly] => 0 [show_help_tip] => 0 [help_tip] => [show_help_text] => 0 [help_text_position] => block [help_text] => [additional_html_attributes] => [credits] => 0 [id] => 0 [searchable_simple] => 1 [searchable_advanced] => date_range [searchable_advanced_caption] => Date Range [searchable_advanced_items] => [searchable_advanced_condition_type] => strict [validation_message] => Invalid input. ) [separator] => . ) )
```

so the field i want to target is the one which has the [name] date-of-incident. (the 3rd one above)

i tried to modify the loop so target this specific record like so

```
<?php if ( !empty($this->fields) ) 
{
    foreach ($this->fields as $field)
    {
        print_r($field);
        if($field[name] == "date-of-incident")
        {
            echo "Date of incident here";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class='span3'>";
            echo RSDirectoryFilter::getInstance($field, $options)->generate();
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
} ?>
```

but this just crashes the site but doesnt give an error message, i assume i am using `if($field[name] == "date-of-incident")` incorrectly?

Appreciate any help
Thanks

Luke

Comment: If the site 'crashes' there is an error message and you just need to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note from your `print_r($field);` that the output says they are Objects i.e. `stdClass Object`

You therefore address the `name` property using the object notation `->` and not the array notation.

```
<?php 
if ( !empty($this->fields) ) {
    foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
        //print_r($field);

        // here is the change
        if($field->name == "date-of-incident") {
            echo "Date of incident here";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='span3'>";
            echo RSDirectoryFilter::getInstance($field, $options)->generate();
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
} 
?>
```